# ride is not working with appium/android studio

Tags: python, android, appium, robotframework

I am new to python/robot and got some problems with appium connected to it.
Why I think it is an appium? Cause other test suites, like the ones with webbrowser works fine. There is no problem with using chrome for browser testing.

I am getting an error:

> FAIL : ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.',
> ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Some logs:

> 20201120 11:01:57.896 :  INFO : ${emulator} = True
>  20201120
> 11:01:57.913 :  INFO : Running command 'appium -p 4723 2>&1'.
> 20201120 11:02:00.141 :  INFO : 
>  ${output} = [35m[Appium][39m
> Welcome to Appium v1.19.0
>  [35m[HTTP][39m Could not start REST
> http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use.
> Please make sure there is no other instance of thi...
>  20201120
> 11:02:05.245 :  FAIL : No application is open
>  20201120
> 11:02:05.247 :  WARN : Keyword 'a.Capture Page Screenshot' could not
> be run on failure: No application is open
>  20201120 11:02:05.257 :
> FAIL : ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.',
> ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

There is a lot info about that error but i could not find anything to suit me.
I am using python 3.7.3, android studio 4.1 and installed, by pip, following libraries:

> robotframework
>  robotframework-ride
> robotframework-selenium2library
> robotframework-databaselibrary
>  robotframework-requests
> robotframework-jsonlibrary
>  robotframework-sshlibrary
> robotframework-httplibrary
>  robotframework-appiumlibrary

What more info should I add?

Comment: You should mention the operating system you are using, and also a minimal Test Case example, or at least how connect to Appium from Robot Framework.